# Converting SQL Server UDF to inline table-valued function

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am new here and new to SQL. I got this tip to create a scalar function that extends the functionality of the built-in `DateAdd` function (namely to exclude weekends and holidays). It is working fine for a single date but when I use it on a table, it is extremely slow.

I have seen some recommendation to use inline table-valued function instead.  Would anyone be so kind to point me in the direction, how I would go about converting the below to inline table-valued function? I greatly appreciate it.

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[CalcWorkDaysAddDays]
    (@StartDate AS DATETIME, @Days AS INT) 
RETURNS DATE 
AS 
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @Count INT = 0 
    DECLARE @WorkDay INT = 0 
    DECLARE @Date DATE = @StartDate 

    WHILE @WorkDay < @Days 
    BEGIN 
        SET @Count = @Count - 1 
        SET @Date = DATEADD(DAY, @Count, @StartDate) 

        IF NOT (DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @Date) IN (1,7) OR 
               EXISTS (SELECT * FROM RRCP_Calendar WHERE Is_Holiday = 1 AND Calendar_Date = @Date)) 
        BEGIN 
            SET @WorkDay = @WorkDay + 1 
        END 
    END 

    RETURN @Date 
END
```

Comment: It is slow because scalar functions are slow. And this one is even slower because of the loop. Can you explain what this is doing? I am certain this can be done in a single select statement which will facilitate an inline table valued function.

Comment: HI Sean, I am using this function to add or subtract a date.  Say [dbo].[CalcWorkDaysAddDays], getdate(), 2 would return Sept 8, 2017 since it is adding two days.  This function is similar to DateAdd but it is excluding weekends and holidays

Comment: Your function is returning a date - shouldn't it return the WorkDay value, i.e., the number of workdays from the StartDate through Days?

Comment: it's supposed to return a date.

Comment: Here is another hint for you: never use a loop in SQL.  never.  don't do it.  ever.  never use a loop.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick...

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.tfn_CalcWorkDaysAddDays 
(
    @StartDate DATETIME,
    @Days INT
)
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING AS 
RETURN
    SELECT 
        TheDate = MIN(x.Calendar_Date)
    FROM (  
            SELECT TOP (@Days)
                c.Calendar_Date
            FROM 
                dbo.RRCP_Calendar c
            WHERE 
                c.Calendar_Date < @StartDate
                AND c.Is_Holiday = 0
                AND c.is_Weekday = 1    -- this should be part of your calendar table. do not calculate on the fly.
            ORDER BY
                c.Calendar_Date DESC
            ) x;
GO
```

Note: for best performance, you'll want a unique, filtered, nonclustered index on on your calendar table...

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX uix_RRCPCalendar_CalendarDate_IsHoliday_isWeekday ON dbo.RRCP_Calendar (
    Calendar_Date, Is_Holiday, is_Weekday)
WHERE Is_Holiday = 0 AND is_Weekday = 1;
```

Comment: Hi Jason, thanks for taking the time to help.  I can't seem to get the result right.  I ran this select * from [dbo].[tfn_CalcWorkDaysAddDays]('09/05/2017',1) and got this 2017-08-07 00:00:00.000.  It seems a bit off.

Comment: I worked from the idea that you're original code was producing the desired results. All I did was modify it just enough to plug in my own Calendar table so that I could get results based on a given set parameter values, and then wrote new code that consistently produce an identical result. If your original function is producing a different value, let me know the parameter values being used and the desired results... and I'll try to identify the breakdown.

Comment: I just checked those specific parameter values (2017-09-05 & 1) using my calendar table. I'm coming up with 2017-09-01 with both your code and mine.

Comment: I upvoted this comment: >>>I worked from the idea that you're original code was producing the desired results<<< I did the same because the description is one thing, but the code does quite another thing. As the post was saying that the code produces correct results, I also just rewrote it. I changed my code some minutes ago to produce what is described by words, but the question is not correct. Instead of posting incorrect code saying that it produces the right result, the OP should give us the intput and the desired output

Comment: @sepupic 100% agreed.

Answer (score 0):

> Say [dbo].[CalcWorkDaysAddDays], getdate(), 2 would return Sept 8,
>   2017 since it is adding two days. This function is similar to DateAdd
>   but it is excluding weekends and holidays

The code you've posted doesn't do this.
But if you want the result described, the function can be smth like this:

```
alter FUNCTION [dbo].[CalcWorkDaysAddDays_inline](@StartDate As DateTime,@Days AS INT) 
returns table 
as return
with cte as
(
select *,
       ROW_NUMBER() over(order by Calendar_Date) as rn
from RRCP_Calendar
where Calendar_Date > @StartDate and @Days > 0
      and not (DATEPART(WEEKDAY,Calendar_Date) IN (1,7) or Is_Holiday = 1)

union ALL

select *,
       ROW_NUMBER() over(order by Calendar_Date desc) as rn
from RRCP_Calendar
where Calendar_Date < @StartDate and @Days < 0
      and not (DATEPART(WEEKDAY,Calendar_Date) IN (1,7) or Is_Holiday = 1)


)
select cast(Calendar_Date as date) as dt
from cte
where rn = abs(@Days);
```

Comment: Hi sepupic, thank you for your response.  I ran your function as SELECT * from [dbo].[CalcWorkDaysAddDays_inline]('09/05/2017', 1) and I got this "2017-08-07".  It seems off.  Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Try this and see if it returns the same values as your function, just without the loop:

```
SELECT WorkDays =
    DATEADD(WEEKDAY, @Days, @StartDate) -
    (SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM RRCP_Calendar
    WHERE Is_Holiday = 1
    AND Calendar_Date >= @StartDate
    AND Calendar_Date <= DATEADD(DAY, @Days, @StartDate)
    )
```

And yes, you can sometimes get substantially better performance with a non-procedural table-valued-function, but you have to set it up right. Look up SARGability and non-procedural table-valued-functions for more info, but if the above query works, this should do the trick:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SelectWorkDaysAddDays(@StartDate DATE, @Days INT)
RETURNS TABLE
AS

RETURN
    SELECT WorkDays =
        DATEADD(WEEKDAY, @Days, @StartDate) -
        (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM RRCP_Calendar
        WHERE Is_Holiday = 1
        AND Calendar_Date >= @StartDate
        AND Calendar_Date <= DATEADD(DAY, @Days, @StartDate)
        )
GO
```

And then you call the function by using an OUTER APPLY join:

```
SELECT y.foo
    , y.bar
    , dt.WorkDays
FROM dbo.YourTable y
    OUTER APPLY dbo.SelectWorkDaysAddDays(@StartDate, @Days) dt
```

Comment: Hi Russell, thanks for your response.  I tried saving the function and got this error message:  sg 206, Level 16, State 2, Procedure SelectWorkDaysAddDays, Line 6 [Batch Start Line 0]
Operand type clash: date is incompatible with int
 Any suggestion?